# Is there a way to get Finder to remember all my tabs and reopen them after restarting?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

Just like with Terminal, I tend to have many Finder tabs open most of the time. Sometimes, I need to restart Finder and OneDrive (e.g., see [https://superuser.com/questions/1546441/very-high-cpu-usage-for-distnoted-on-mac#:~:text=Distnoted%20is%20a%20system%20message,and%20is%20tied%20to%20finder.](https://superuser.com/questions/1546441/very-high-cpu-usage-for-distnoted-on-mac#:%7E:text=Distnoted%20is%20a%20system%20message,and%20is%20tied%20to%20finder.)), and it is troublesome to reopen each Finder tab one by one. Terminal has a nice feature to remember all my tabs and even re-run the commands that were last run in each of them. Is there any way to do something similar with Finder?

Comment: Finder always remembers… unless you kill the process. Next time try Relaunch instead [Opt/right click in Dock] & see if that will still fix the OneDrive issue.

Comment: Thanks @tetsujin, Relaunch works for this!

Comment: I'd kill for Terminal's Windows Groups in the Finder. I submitted it as a Feature Request to Apple years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments - The method in the linked question requires Finder to be killed. This will prevent its remembering currently-open windows.

It appears in the particular circumstance that Relaunching Finder is sufficient - Opt/right click in Dock - which also preserves its current structure.

Comment: I've not found this: Relaunching Finder (from Force Quit menu or Dock) loses the active tab for me. As does rebooting.

Comment: @benwiggy What version of MacOS are you using? I'm on Catalina, 10.15.6

Comment: @auspicious99 I'm on Big Sur, but IME, Finder has been like that for years.

Comment: @benwiggy I thought so too. I don't know how it could remember and restore my tabs today. Maybe also because I had just merged all tabs to one finder window, before doing the relaunch.

Comment: I rarely use tabs, so I felt I ought to double-check this works as expected. It does, restoring regular windows and tabs… so long as you give it a couple of minutes to 'remember' before relaunching Finder. If you do it too quickly it hasn't updated the current state. *caveat:* I'm still on Mojave, so behaviour may have changed since.